# get difference with previous date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JSON , how do i get difference between the previous date for num_followers for each website ?

like for website yqq on 15-02-2022 I need to get the difference between the num_followers from 14-02-2022  and update num_followers with difference value

```
[
    {
        "date": "2022-02-15",
        "websites": [
            {
                "website_name": "yqq",
                "num_followers": "454421"
            },
            {
                "website_name": "soundcloud",
                "num_followers": "757127"
            },
            {
                "website_name": "twitter",
                "num_followers": "21779161"
            },
            {
                "website_name": "soundcloud",
                "num_followers": "757054"
            },
            {
                "website_name": "triller",
                "num_followers": "5196"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-02-14",
        "websites": [
            {
                "website_name": "yqq",
                "num_followers": "123058219"
            },
            {
                "website_name": "triller",
                "num_followers": "5195"
            },
            {
                "website_name": "tiktok",
                "num_followers": "17100000"
            },
            {
                "website_name": "instagram",
                "num_followers": "123059626"
            },
            {
                "website_name": "tiktok",
                "num_followers": "17100000"
            },
            {
                "website_name": "tiktok",
                "num_followers": "17100000"
            },
            {
                "website_name": "soundcloud",
                "num_followers": "756956"
            },
        ]
    
    }
]
```

Comment: You do not understand your needs, can you elaborate?  What num_followers is for

Comment: something like `const differences = input[0].websites.map(({website_name, num_followers}) => ({ website_name, change_followers: num_followers - (input[1].websites.find(({website_name: x}) => x === website_name)?.num_followers || 0)}));` will give you a new  array of the differences - though, only of the ones that have entries in the latest (i.e. first) data - but this should be a start for you to actually write some code

Comment: @vueAng - I think it's you that doesn't understand the OP's needs if you don't even know what `num_followers` is for

Comment: do you mean comparing the dates?

Comment: @Bravo this works but its removing dates , I want to retain the original array

Comment: yeah sure, but it's a START - think of `differences` being the `websites` property. Did you want to modify `input[0]`? or did you want a new object?

Comment: @Bravo thanks I was to solve this based on your code

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me thanks to @Bravo

```
rdiff = [];
          for (var k = 0; k < r.length; k++) {

            if (typeof r[k + 1] != 'undefined') {

              var differences = r[k].websites.map(function (_ref) {
                var _r$websites$find;

                var website_name = _ref.website_name,
                  num_followers = _ref.num_followers,
                  website_id = _ref.website_id;
                return {
                  website_name: website_name,
                  website_id: website_id,
                  num_followers: num_followers - (((_r$websites$find = r[k + 1].websites.find(function (_ref2) {
                    var x = _ref2.website_name;
                    return x === website_name;
                  })) === null || _r$websites$find === void 0 ? void 0 : _r$websites$find.num_followers) || 0)
                };
              });

              // console.log(differences);
              diff = {
                "date": r[k].date,
                "websites": differences
              }
              rdiff.push(diff);

            }
          }

          // console.log(rdiff);
```